# How to run a Java application on Ec2?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, amazon-ec2

I want to deploy a a project to ec2. It was modify in Intellij which used MAVEN. It work perfect in Intellij. Below is the configuration of Intellij.

[image]

I have tried command line like java, javac. These kind of comment lines are all failed. I am wondering there must some way to convert Intellij configuration to command lines. I was relying too much on IDE. XD. Now I am regreted.

Comment: If you use maven, you can also use the exec plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by myself.

1. Use **`mvn package`** to generated jar file for maven project.
2. **`nohup java xx.jar debug.xml &`** use this to run jar in shell. By using this command line, when exit (abort remote connection), the process / command will not get killed.
3. Command line **`jcmd`** is used to check running process pid.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 is the amazon cloud service for instances. If you aren't very experienced with it - the easiest you can do is to hire a machine with your fav operating system - for example Windows and use remote desktop to log in it and just do your normal IDE setup and run your app. You will have your app running on your instance and it will be working, even it is done the hard way. I will get downvotes for that, but it will work as a Swiss watch.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the kind of EC2 instance you're using.

For me would be simpler if it was a Linux instance.

I'll connect via ssh and git clone my project there from my bitbucket/github repository.

Then I'll use Maven, and there are many different options to run your project with Maven.

As suggested in the comments you could use the `exec` plugin.

But even in this way you'll have a list of problems to overcame.

For example your linux instance does not came with an preinstalled Java Runtime.

You have to install at least Java and Maven (choose ubuntu distro, so you can do easily with a package manager like `apt-get`).

Or, for example, another not easy task is connect via ssh to a Linux instance.

AWS generates a key.pem file that you have to use in order to successfully connect to your instance.

```
ssh -i .ssh/your-key-file.pem username@your-ec2-instance-address
```

And again, AWS does not tell you the name of the default user you must use to connect to your EC2 instance (if you choose ubuntu distro the username is `ubuntu`).

And again, when you save `your-key-file.pem` in your computer it must have the right permission

```
-rw-------@ 1 freedev  staff  1692 Apr 21 09:46 /Users/freedev/.ssh/your-key-file.pem
```

or your ssh client wont read it.

...looking back it was really a long way make a deploy on a EC2 instance.